# How to set the id for a razor drop down list

Tags: razor

I am not used to using razor and I was wondering how would I give my Dropdown list and id of "lstClub"

This is my View with the dropdown list that I want to set the id on

```
<div>
    <h3 class="text-primary">Select your team</h3>
    @Html.DropDownList("ClubID", String.Empty)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) of `DropDownList` method.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```

The third parameter is a dictionary object where you will pass the html attributes you want to set for the dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClubID",new List<SelectListItem>(),new { id="lstClub"})
```

This will render a dropdown with Id `lstClub` and name `ClubID`, but with no options.

```
<select id="lstClub" name="ClubID"></select>
```

If you wan't options, you can replace the second parameter,the empty list `(new List<SelectListItem>()`) with a  list with items.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for